# Shared element back transition not working with recyclerview In ViewPage2

Tags: java, android, material-ui

I have created a recyclerview in a viewpaper2, and want to use share emplement to move to update page. However shared element back transition is not working with recyclerview.

In Adapter

```
todoItemViewHolder.itemTodoBinding.cardItem.setTransitionName("update_" + position);
            todoItemViewHolder.itemTodoBinding.cardItem.setOnClickListener(view -> iClickItem.DetaiItem(todoItem,todoItemViewHolder.itemTodoBinding.cardItem));
```

In AllItemFragment

```
 todoItemAdapter.setClickListenner(new TodoItemAdapter.IClickItemToDo() {
            @Override
            public void DetaiItem(TodoItem todoItem, CardView cardView) {
                clickDetailItem(todoItem,cardView);
            }
```

```
 private void clickDetailItem(TodoItem todoItem, CardView cardView) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("object_TodoItem", todoItem);
        bundle.putString("transition",cardView.getTransitionName() );

        FragmentNavigator.Extras extras = new FragmentNavigator.Extras.Builder()
                .addSharedElement(cardView,cardView.getTransitionName())
                .build();


        Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.updateItemFragment, bundle,null,extras);
    }
```

In UpdateFragment

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setSharedElementEnterTransition(new ChangeBounds());

        fragmentUpdateItemBinding = FragmentUpdateItemBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        mView = fragmentUpdateItemBinding.getRoot();

        todoItemViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(TodoItemViewModel.class);
        fragmentUpdateItemBinding.setTodoItemViewModel(todoItemViewModel);

        datePickerCreated = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
                .setTitleText("Select date").setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds())
                .build();

        datePickerCompleted = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker()
                .setTitleText("Select date").setSelection(MaterialDatePicker.todayInUtcMilliseconds())
                .build();
        return mView;
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation specifically about using shared element transitions and returning back to a RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate#recyclerview)?